# Issue in dumping/getting items ( keys and values) in localStorage in python selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, local-storage

I'm trying to get data/items with keys and values from the local storage and I'm using the following python code with selenium. Actually, the code works for a single item in the local storage but if there are more than one items in the local storage, it gives empty object {}, If anyone knows what's the issue please response. thank you

```
from webbrowser import Chrome
from selenium import webdriver



class LocalStorage:

   def __init__(self, driver: webdriver) :
    self.driver = driver

   def goto(self):
    self.driver.get("https://tribune.com.pk")
    return self

   def __len__(self):
    return self.driver.execute_script("return window.localStorage.length;")



   def items(self) :
    return self.driver.execute_script( \
        "var ls = window.localStorage, items = {}; " \
        "for (var i = 0, k; i < ls.length; ++i) " \
        "  items[k = ls.key(i)] = ls.getItem(k); " \
        "return items; ")


   def __iter__(self):
    return self.items().__iter__()

   def __repr__(self):
    return self.items().__str__()




driver =webdriver.Chrome()
storage = LocalStorage(driver).goto()
print(storage)
```

Comment: Does Javascript guarantee that the `k = ls.key(i)` will be evaluated before the `ls.getItem(k)`?  That seems like a very dangerous assumption to make.

Comment: I checked this on the chrome console and it's working

Comment: Seems like you're trying to make a named array here?  Don't think that'll work in JS.  Just use index, or push it.... or create key/value array and then add that?   I think Selenium has also added methods for getting/setting localstorage.  Maybe check here:  https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/index.html?org/openqa/selenium/html5/LocalStorage.html